# error to pass data from pentaho HTTP Client to Json Input

Tags: httpclient, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am trying to load json data from the following link http://swapi.co/api/films/
into pentaho.

I used 3 steps Generate Rows, HTTP Client and Json Input

**Generate Rows Step :**

```
Limit: 1
Name: movies
Type: string
Value:http://swapi.co/api/films/?format=json
```

**HTTP Client Step:**

```
General Tab
 Accept URL from field? Yes
 URL field name: movies
 Result fieldname: json

fields Tab
 Name: movies
 Parameters: movies
```

**Json Input Step:**

```
(Fields Tab)
  (would like to get all the fields in the "results" array eg. title,episode, director.....)
  Name: title
  Path: $.results[0]
  Type: String
(fields Tab)
  Name: movies
  Parameters: movies
```

I get this error:

```
2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : at  org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jsoninput.JsonReader.readString(JsonReader.java:127)
2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ... 7 more 
2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
```

Comment: Please post code, or screen shots of your setup.

Comment: Hi @bolav, I have just amended the question with more details. any suggestions on how I went wrong. I am a fresher to pentaho pdi. regards

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @bolav 2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jsoninput.JsonReader.readString(JsonReader.java:127)
2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  ... 7 more
2016/02/24 12:05:00 - Json Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)

Comment: What does the preview show for json after HTTP Client? I think you should remove the entries inside the HTTP, fields tab (movies)

Comment: @bolav When I use it on its own with a downloaded version of the dataset. it seems fine. My issue is when I want to load data automatically to Generate Rows step and stream it through HTTP Client.

Comment: Updated my answer now. Looks like the problem is with the api, when using Pentaho HTTP Client.

Comment: cool Thanks very much. was really wondering now @bolav

Answer (score 0):

That URL doesn't give pure json output.  Try using http://swapi.co/api/films/?format=json instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Clubok, but after amending the path in the Generate Rows value, I am still having an error with the Json Input step.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that swapi.co is using [Cloudfare Browser Integrity Check](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-), and it doesn't give a real response to Pentaho HTTP Client:

```
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1>
          <span class="cf-error-type" data-translate="error">Error</span>
          <span class="cf-error-code">1010</span>
          <small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 279b7723caa3426d &bull; 2016-02-24 13:20:00 UTC</small>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline" data-translate="error_desc">Access denied</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (swapi.co) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (279b7723caa3426d-ua31).</p>
          </div>
```

Here is an example to use the JSON Input Step:

[image: JSON Input Step]

Comment: Thanks @bolav for clarifying the step. but I am still getting an error. Are my entries of Generate Rows (1 entry: movie) and HTTP Client (the Get Fields populated only movie from previuos)not the issue?.